# NC file is not at the correct size and location

Tags: qgis, netcdf, format

I'm trying to display on QGIS a .nc file of sea temperature of the Eastern Mediterranean, but it doesn't have the good size and isn't at the good place on the OpenStreetMap layer that is under (see image below).

[image]

All the CRS are WGS84.

Does someone know how to fix that?

Comment: Are you sure the crs of the nc file is wgs84? Have you done anything with the layer, for example "Assign projection"? Maybe you (or the source of it) have defined it incorrectly

Comment: Can you take a picture of your "information" properties of your layer.

Comment: Since the top left of your image is on top of "null island", I'm guessing you need to both scale and translate your image.

Comment: I had assigned the projection of the netcdf layer to WGS84 (there was no projection assigned when I first loaded it). But finally I found an R script that permit to convert ncdf to raster and then it fits correctly in QGIS :) Thank you for your comments !